# IntelliJ Idea not update remote Tomcat, only redeploy works

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

In IntelliJ Idea I've very basic Spring Boot Starter project configured with Tomcat in scope "Provided".

I've configuration for "Tomcat remote" in IDE and everything seems properly set.

[image: IntelliJ Tomcat configuration]

My Tomcat version 8 is not modified except this file with JMX configuration:

[image: Tomcat setenv.sh file]

I can start tomcat with "catalina run". When I click on the button "Run" in IDE to deploy project then

[image]

project is successfully deployed to remote Tomcat and is working.

**Problem is** that Hot Swap by pressins "Build project" button doesn't work at all even for basic html classes. Therefore when I make some changes I have to Redeploy entire project which is **very time consuming.**

How to resolve it?

Comment: Did you try this: https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/get-tomcat-hot-swap-work-with-intellij/ ?

Answer (score 0):

what is your spring version ? - hope 1.3 and above

In the spring you have a tool named dev-tools add the entry in your pom file to support hot swap and reduce development time.[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A70NMxV13TI)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2. In eclipse we have a option build automatically ,make sure corresponding option is checked in the used ide(IntelliJ).